# Angular + Capacitor: Input not aligned with Keyboard

Tags: angular, forms, input, keyboard, capacitor

I'm developing an app in the angular environment. I mainly test and develop the app via browser and then build it via capacitor to run as a native app on iOS and Android.

I am now facing a bug, which heavily affects the overall user experience, where whenever the user presses on an input field (in the final iOS build) the iOS (Capacitor) Keyboard opens as desired, while also moving the input field away from the users focus. Sometimes it is even completely hidden by other UI elements.

Is there a way to programmatically move the focused input field to be always displayed exactly over the keyboard?

I also tried changing the Capacitor Keyboard "resize" settings (native, body, ionic, none) with no improvement.

I've attached examples and the html for my input form below. Thank you!

[HTML FORM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vzUA.png)

Example Video: https://i.imgur.com/5NRsaX0.mp4

Comment: user margin-top instead of padding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sur it will work for you, but please, try to

1. Move this part into the [ion-header](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/header) [image] if not done so.
2. Use [ion-content](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/content) instead of `<div class="content">`
3. If you would like the targeted input to be directly under the header, then you could try to use the `scrollToPoint` method from `ion--content` like this

```html
<input (focus)="inputTrigger($event)">
```

```js
export class YourPage {
    @ViewChild(IonContent) theContent: IonContent;

   // 
    inputTrigger(event) {
      const position = event.target.getBoundingClientRet()
      this.theContent.scrollToPoint(0,position.top).then(()=>{})
    }
}
```

*It wont work out of the box cause I don't exactly know your code, but it may guide you to the answer ;)*

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer Raphaël! Since i’m currently only using capacitor + angular, i cant use the ion-framework elements. I will convert my project into an ionic project to test your approach. Is there a way to easily adapt the existing angular project or do i have to create a completely new project? 

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm also using angular ;) but it isn't a reason to not use the power of ionic and I would heavily recommend you to use it sinc their component are build for smartphone devices, which take care of the difference between devices, required padding, etc...You only have to add `ionicModule` into the import inside your `.module.ts` file.

Comment: Worked beautifully! Thanks again +1

Comment: @lem5730 I would be tanksful if you could then upvote the answer ;)